# PHP "for loop" to gather data

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

**How to loop this thing to gather data of multiple $objectId? Like from $objectId 1038 to 1048.**

Below Im presentig full script that can collect data. In line  `$objectId = ""; //I want to gather info about IDs lets say from 1038 - 1048` should be the loop I think, but Ive failed to do it good.

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post" id="myForm">
  <table cellpadding="2" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="264" rowspan="2" valign="top"><?php 

    function transformHTML($string)
    {
        $string = trim($string);
        $string = utf8_decode($string);
        $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
        $string = str_replace("#", "&#35;", $string);
        $string = str_replace("%", "&#37;", $string);

        return $string;
    }

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }

    if($_POST['submit']) { 

        $objectId = ""; //I want to gather info about IDs lets say from 1038 - 1048

            $error_B = "<span class=error>Error #2:<br> Does the item exist (ID: " . $objectId . ")?</span><br>";

            $lines = file('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/viewitem.ws?obj=' . $objectId);
            foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
                $lineCrawl = htmlspecialchars($line);
                $StringSum = "$StringSum$lineCrawl";
            }
            $parsedGuidePrice = get_string_between($StringSum, "Current guide price", "Today");
            $parsedItemName = get_string_between($StringSum, "&lt;title&gt;", " - Grand Exchange - RuneScape&lt;/title&gt;");
            $parsedItemIconUrl  = get_string_between($StringSum, '&lt;meta property=&quot;og:image&quot; content=&quot;', '&quot; /&gt;');

            $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^\.kbm0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);

            if (strpos($guideprice,'k') !== false) {
                $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
                $guideprice *= 100;
            } else if (strpos($guideprice,'m') !== false) {
                $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
                $guideprice *= 100000;
            } else if (strpos($guideprice,'b') !== false) {
                $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
                $guideprice *= 100000000;
            } 
            if ($guideprice == "") { 
                echo $error_B; 
            } else { 
                echo "<img src='" . $parsedItemIconUrl . "' class='parsedItemIconUrl'>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<strong>" . $parsedItemName . "</strong> guide price: <strong>" . $guideprice . "</strong>"; 
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<small>(Item ID: " . $objectId . ")</small><br><br><br>";
            }
    }
    ?></td>
      <td width="172"></td>
      <td width="99"><input type="submit" name="submit" alt="Get yesterday's averge market price" title="Get yesterday's averge market price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td></td>
      <td><input value="Reset" type="button" name="reset" alt="Reset the form" title="Reset the form" onClick="javascript:window.location = '';"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you specify what theproblem actually is? What results your expected, what you're actually getting?

Comment: What I did was adding +1 to $objectId but program still was reading the same URL :(

Comment: It works, thank you! What I did was on the last line of `if($_POST['submit']) { }` I've added `$objectId +=1` and looped all inside it with `for($objectId = 1038; $objectId <= 1048; $objectId ++)` { but It faild. Can I know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post" id="myForm">
  <table cellpadding="2" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="264" rowspan="2" valign="top"><?php 

    function transformHTML($string)
    {
        $string = trim($string);
        $string = utf8_decode($string);
        $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES);
        $string = str_replace("#", "&#35;", $string);
        $string = str_replace("%", "&#37;", $string);

        return $string;
    }

    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }

    function echoObjectIdStuff($objectId) {
        $error_B = "<span class=error>Error #2:<br> Does the item exist (ID: " . $objectId . ")?</span><br>";

        $lines = file('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/viewitem.ws?obj=' . $objectId);
        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
            $lineCrawl = htmlspecialchars($line);
            $StringSum = "$StringSum$lineCrawl";
        }
        $parsedGuidePrice = get_string_between($StringSum, "Current guide price", "Today");
        $parsedItemName = get_string_between($StringSum, "&lt;title&gt;", " - Grand Exchange - RuneScape&lt;/title&gt;");
        $parsedItemIconUrl  = get_string_between($StringSum, '&lt;meta property=&quot;og:image&quot; content=&quot;', '&quot; /&gt;');

        $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^\.kbm0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);

        if (strpos($guideprice,'k') !== false) {
            $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
            $guideprice *= 100;
        } else if (strpos($guideprice,'m') !== false) {
            $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
            $guideprice *= 100000;
        } else if (strpos($guideprice,'b') !== false) {
            $guideprice = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $parsedGuidePrice);
            $guideprice *= 100000000;
        } 
        if ($guideprice == "") { 
            echo $error_B; 
        } else { 
            echo "<img src='" . $parsedItemIconUrl . "' class='parsedItemIconUrl'>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<strong>" . $parsedItemName . "</strong> guide price: <strong>" . $guideprice . "</strong>"; 
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<small>(Item ID: " . $objectId . ")</small><br><br><br>";
        }
    }

    if($_POST['submit']) { 
        for($id = 1038;  $id <= 1048; $id++) {
            echoObjectIdStuff($id);
        }
    }

    ?></td>
      <td width="172"></td>
      <td width="99"><input type="submit" name="submit" alt="Get yesterday's averge market price" title="Get yesterday's averge market price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td></td>
      <td><input value="Reset" type="button" name="reset" alt="Reset the form" title="Reset the form" onClick="javascript:window.location = '';"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! What I did was on the last line of `if($_POST['submit']) { }` I've added `$objectId +=1` and looped all inside it with `for($objectId = 1038;  $objectId <= 1048; $objectId ++) {` but It faild. Can I know why?

Comment: I assume you want $objectId to increase in 1 everytime someone submits the form? if so, PHP doesn't keep the state of the variable between requests, you should look into sessions to accomplish that. Otherwise you don't need to do +=1, the  $objectId++ part of the for loop does this for each iteration.

Read more about sessions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
And about for loops: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: thanks you for respond. Well approved answer for this question helpt, but this what I provided in commend above not - $objectID increase in 1 everytime for loop ends. (in my not working solution ofc)